# How to change size cite reference number in latex

Tags: citing

I am trying to change the size of the bibliography reference

[image: output]

here \cite{29} is smaller than normal. why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\setcitestyle{square}
\section{Motivations and Problem Description}
The increased volume of goods moved by road in the 
European Union will significantly increase travel time 
and freight transportation costs.\cite{29} 

\begin{thebibliography}{3}
    
\bibitem{29}
    Abtin Nourmohammadzadeh and Sven Hartmann (2018): 
\emph{Fuel Efficient Truck Platooning with 
Time Restrictions and Multiple Speeds Solved by a 
Particle Swarm Optimisation},D. 
Fagan et al. (Eds.): TPNC 2018, LNCS 11324, 
pp.188-200, DOI 10.1007/978-3-030-04070-3 15, 
Springer Nature Switzerland AG, 
Clausthal-Zellerfeld, Germany.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The output you show is not the output I get from running your example code.  I get an error `! Undefined control sequence. l.3 \setcitestyle`. Please make sure that your example compiles without error and actually shows the issue you are asking about.

Comment: For now all I can say that it looks as though you are getting superscript citations. Superscripts are traditionally a bit smaller than the numbers on the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The presence of the `\setcitestyle` directive in your sample code strongly suggests that you use the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) citation management package. Moreover, the screenshot you posted suggests that your code contains the instruction

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

somewhere in the preamble -- or in some other package that's loaded in the preamble.

If these educated guesses are on target, the easiest way to achieve your formatting objective is to replace `super` with `numbers`, i.e., to run

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

in the preamble.